# capture a new image using existing image with camera app in android

Tags: android, screenshot, android-camera

I am planning to make an application in *Android*, in which we can select an image from the gallery and using that image and *Android Camera* app we have to capture a new image and saved to the *SD Card*.

Selecting the image from gallery and opening camera app can be done by Intent, but how to combine these two.

I also searched for `screen shot` option in *Android* but it says ***the device has to be rooted for this because of security purpose***.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: am I the only one that did not understood the question...?

Comment: sorry for my bad English,actually needed to export an image that i have selected from gallery to the camera app in android.Then with that pic i have to capture a new image using camera app.

Comment: what do you mean "with that pic, I have to capture a new image" ?? replace the old picture, or what?

Comment: image from the gallery will be there in the surface of the camera,so when i capture the picture using camera the newly captured picture will contain the old picture from gallery.just like image editing

Answer (score 1):

private static final int GET_IMAGE = 2;

```
cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(FotografiActivity.this).setTitle("Byggekort")
            .setMessage(R.string.camera_open_msg).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    takePhoto();
                }
            }).create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

private void takePhoto() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)));
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}




public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == GET_IMAGE) {
                targetUri = data.getData();
                fotografiImageView.setImageURI(targetUri);
                selectedImagePath =getPath(targetUri);
                Bitmap captureBmp;
                try {
                    captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
                            targetUri);
                    applicationActivity.dataArray.put(PHOTO_URI, captureBmp);
                    applicationActivity.dataUri.put(URI1, selectedImagePath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the takePhoto is the function called on the click event of Button named cameraButton..... in that function, i called activity for opening the gallery of the device...and started the activity by using  ...StartActivityforResult ...this is inbuilt in android...which executes onActivityResult....